# cross-account-access between 3 AWS accounts using assumeRule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

We have a service in **`AWS-Account-A`** which will copy some files with               `ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'` to a s3 bucket in **`AWS-Account-B`** . Now there is a **`AWS-Account-C`** which already have a assumeRule ( which a S3 Read access policy is attached to it ) from AWS-Account-B, and S3 bucket policy already gave read access to AWS-Account-C rules, So the problem is, AWS-Account-C : **`Can't`** read those files which uploaded from AWS-Account-A and only **`CAN`** read files which uploaded using AWS-Account-B itself.

I know it's a reallay compliated secnario, but as far as I understand, it's a ownership problem. The bucket policy applies only to objects that are owned by the bucket owner, So it's like , `X` own some files, and he copy it to `Y`, now `Z` can't get it from `Y`, because it's not owned by `Y`.

If anyone faced to this kind of sencarios before and have solution, I really appreciate it to give some guidance.

Comment: So that we can try to reproduce your situation, please show the policies you have used (you can remove sensitive names) and the exact steps you took when copying the files (eg the command issued).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you used Account-A to copy files to a bucket owned by Account-B but now the copied files are owned by Account-A. This is why Account-C cannot access them. Account-C does not have the required permission.

The correct procedure is to create a role in Account-B to be assumed by Account-A. Then before Account-A copies file to the bucket in Account-B, it assumes the Account-B role. Now files copied to the bucket will be owned by Account-B.

For the files currently in the Account-B bucket, while using Account-B's credentials do an inplace copy. This will switch the ownership to Account-B.

Here is an example inplace copy. Note: No data is transferred over the internet just within S3 so it executes quickly.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mykey s3://mybucket/mykey --storage-class STANDARD
```

The '--recursive' argument to apply to an entire folder of keys.

Warnings:

1) All custom metadata and existing permissions will be lost.

2) Ensure you have backups of your data prior to executing a command such as this.

Comment: This one possible answer. But if you can't assume a role from account B, then you will have to grant full privileges to account B from account A when you push the file. And account B can add a rule that will deny any pushes that don't include that privilege.

Comment: See Controlling ownership of uploaded objects using S3 Object Ownership:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html